# MVC: Is it a good idea to split CSS files by view?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, split, styles

SO I have a big ASP.NET MVC Razor application that has a large Site.css with over 7000 lines of code, we have been discussing splitting that file into multiple files depending on Views.

For example with have the following views:

About Folder

Index.cshtml

Detail.cshtml

---

Contact Folder

Index.cshtml

Detail.cshtml

---

Support Folder

Index.cshtml

Detail.cshtml

and so on...

What we are considering is creating a Common.css file that will be added to the Layout.cshtml

And for each Views folder create a css file specific to those views, is it good practie to do this? Is is it a good idea?

Comment: I would not do that. I think it introduces unnecessary complexity. Just minify the CSS and take advantage of the fact that browsers will cache the file and thus only download it once.

Comment: This is more of an opinionated question.

Comment: I say do it. Split them up if only because it's easier to work with fewer, smaller files than a single, 7000 line file. You can recombine and minify them as part of your build process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep everything in one css file (especially in production) because it requires only one request to get everything and the browser will cache it for future requests. You can make an exception for views that use excessive css (big 'file' size) and not requested frequently (you can track your visitors browse behaviour and optimize the css loading depending on that). For example you can consider splitting the css for a page that users/visitors only request once or not very often.

However I think it is a good idea to split the css files in development. This will keep things conveniently arranged and easy to maintain. Once you've ready with development you can merge the css files and minify them to decrease filesize. you don't have to do this manually. I'm not an ASP.net'er but I'm sure there are libraries out there that do exactly that. Also you could easily write a css merger by yourself. In the end it's just getting the content of all css files and merge them in one file (in the right order). This file can then be passed to a css minifier like http://code.google.com/p/reducisaurus/

An other option could be to embed the correct css in your html view files between style tags. This way you can separate your css without increasing the number of requests. In fact it will decrease the number of requests by minimum one. However this is not a good idea for dynamic pages as the css will always be a part of the http response (so no caching here, unless its a static page that has not been changed)

**EDIT**

So to conclude, I would go for a good library to handle your css. Preferably a library that supports less css as this will keep your css even more organised and a lot easier to maintain. With lessCSS you can import css files, nest classes, define variables, do other logic, etc. Great for developement! In production you simply use the compiled css.

> for asp.net you could use:

http://www.dotlesscss.org/

> for php you could use:

http://leafo.net/lessphp/